# What order to join multiple (over 3) tables and where to put conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I've done quite a bit of reading and testing, and I can get the information I want out of individual queries, but I can't seem to join them to get everything in one table.

Goal - List all containers with the related blocks and the name of the AdminRole.

Here's a visual of the relationships between the tables and fields I need:
[Table Structure Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK7QH.png)

Since I can't attach pictures yet, here's the table descriptions:

- AdminACL

  - adminID (=adminrole_admin.adminID) (EDIT: =adminrole.ID)
  - objectID (=Container.ID)
  - ObjectType (Condition "Container")
- adminrole_admin (EDIT: table not needed)

  - adminroleID (=adminrole.ID)
  - adminID (=AdminACL.adminID)
- adminrole

  - ID (=adminrole_admin.adminroleID) (EDIT: =AdminACL.adminid)
  - name <- Desired field in results table [bonus points for condition not like 'hidden_%']
- Container

  - ID (=AdminACL.objectID)
  - name <- Desired field in results table
- container_block

  - containerID (=Container.ID)
  - blockID (=Block.ID)
- Block

  - ID (=container_block.blockID)
  - name <- Desired field in results table

I've got select statements for each piece, but since it makes for exceptionally messy queries, I tried joins, but end up with empty sets. I'm not sure which table to start with and if I need to use different types of joins and/or in different orders.

Here's the last query I tried before giving up:

```
SELECT C.name, B.name, A.name 
FROM container C
JOIN (SELECT adminid,objected from adminacl where objecttype='Container') ACL ON ACL.objectid=C.id
JOIN adminrole_admin AA ON ACL.adminid=AA.adminid
JOIN (select id,name from adminrole where name not like 'hidden_%') A ON AA.adminid=A.id
JOIN container_block CB ON C.id=CB.containerid
JOIN block B ON CB.blockid=B.id;
```

As much as I'd love the answer, I'd also like to understand how to structure this type of query in the future. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious - just having a hard time relating all the other examples I've looked at with this. TIA!

EDIT: It turns out that adminacl.adminid=adminrole.id, which made things a lot more simple. Also ended up needing the 'hidden' admin roles, which were specific user based permissions added on top of the roles. Based on Russ's answer, this is what my final query ended up being:

```
SELECT container.name, block.name, adminrole.name
FROM block
    LEFT JOIN container_block ON container_block.blockid=block.id
    LEFT JOIN container ON container.id=container_block.containerid
    LEFT JOIN adminacl ON adminacl.objectid=container.id
    JOIN adminrole ON adminrole.id=adminacl.adminid
WHERE
    adminacl.objecttype='Container'
    AND block.blockstatus !=1 #to exclude unassigned blocks
ORDER BY container.name, block.name;
```

Comment: Why are you doing selects within two of the joins?

Comment: That was one method shown where a filter was needed. There are 2742 rows in adminacl, but only 444 of them are of type Container. Adminrole has 1046 records, but only 136 that don't have 'hidden_' in them. Although I suppose those would be weeded out by the containers. Or maybe not... I'm not really sure what the purpose of those roles are, but they appear to be individual admins and not the group roles that we're looking for (the 136).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to start from what I actually want the largest quantity of. From your question, I think you want a list of blocks with containers and admin roles on there, so I started there and left-joined on the additional information to create the list.

```
SELECT Block.name, Container.name, adminrole.name from 
Block
    LEFT JOIN container_block ON container_block.containerid = Block.id
    LEFT JOIN Container ON Container.id = container_block.containerid
    LEFT JOIN AdminACL ON AdminACL.objectid = Container.id
    RIGHT JOIN adminrole_admin ON adminrole_admin.adminid #there could be multiple roles
    LEFT JOIN adminrole ON adminrole.id = adminrole_admin.adminroleID
WHERE 
    AdminACL.ObjectType = "Container"
    AND adminrole.name  not like 'hidden_%'; 
# shouldn't you have a `hidden` column on the table, instead of prefixing the name?
```

*Disclaimer:* I wrote this from memory and didn't even test it on anything, but give it a try, it might set you on the right path.

LEFT JOIN is going to exclude rows that fail the join condition, so you shouldn't get lots of irrelevant blanks, but I'm assuming that there can be many adminroles, so I'm using a RIGHT JOIN to produce rows that contain all possible combinations of the `adminrole` and `Block`. This will mean that the same block appears with different adminroles and the same adminrole will appear on multiple blocks. Your application will need to handle this duplication appropriately.

Comment: I didn't create it and even with my extremely limited SQL knowledge I can tell it's poorly designed, but I've got to work with it...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, though. It has helped me get further. I realized, while looking at one of the partial output tables that there has to be a more direct mapping of AdminRoles to Containers, because we do actually assign those roles to the Container objects.

Some of the queries are in the HTML and some are in Java, but not all of the Java code is available, so it can be challenging figuring out what is where.